# Extracting string between two substrings using grep

Tags: regex, unix, grep

The following extracts almost what I want but not quite:

```
echo 'pie(x=x,labels=c("5.3 %","2.8 %","1.5 %","5.2 %","2.9 %","2.3 %","7.9 %","16.9 %","19.5 %","27.5 %","8.3 %"),main="ChIP",col=c("#445FA2","#EB9D86","#799F7A","#6C527F","#5FA1C1","#E8BB77","#A8C5EF","#FDCDB9","#C6E6B5","#F1D5EE","#B4E1F6"),clockwise=TRUE,border=FALSE,radius=0.9,cex=0.8,init.angle=90,density=100)'|grep -oP '(?<=").*?(?= %)'
```

Output is:

```
5.3
,"2.8
,"1.5
,"5.2
,"2.9
,"2.3
,"7.9
,"16.9
,"19.5
,"27.5
,"8.3
```

Would you please advise how to obtain a 'cleaner' output such as:

```
5.3
2.8
1.5
5.2
2.9
2.3
7.9
16.9
19.5
27.5
8.3
```

Preferably, please base solution on the above grep -oP , but of course other solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only 0-9 and "." characters you can use:

```
grep -oP '(?<=")[\d\.]*?(?= %)'
```

instead of

```
grep -oP '(?<=").*?(?= %)'
```

Note: \d in Perl matches 0-9 whereas
. in Perl matches any character so you escape it to be a literal period character

Comment: thanks! to make it more general towards catching also cases in which a number has a mixer of characters as well, such as: 
echo 'pie(x=x,labels=c("abc5ui.3 %","def2.8 %","1.5ghi %","5.2 %","2.9 %","2.3 %","7.9 %","16.9 %","19.5 %","27.5 %","8.3 %"),main="ChIP",col=c("#445FA2","#EB9D86","#799F7A","#6C527F","#5FA1C1","#E8BB77","#A8C5EF","#FDCDB9","#C6E6B5","#F1D5EE","#B4E1F6"),clockwise=TRUE,border=FALSE,radius=0.9,cex=0.8,init.angle=90,density=100)'|grep -oP '(?<=")[a-zA-Z\d\.]*(?= %)'

Comment: You are more than welcome. Note that you can use \w to replace a-zA-Z0-9 in Perl. Since the P option to grep uses Perl regexp you may find out more by typing: perldoc perlre although my man page for grep warns that -P is experimental.

Comment: Thanks a lot! such as: 
grep 'pie(' EZH2_2libsMerged_posnegMerged_atPRC2MajorStitchedRegions.R|sed -n 2p| grep -oP '(?<=")[\w\d\.]*(?= %)'

Answer (score 0):

A simple matching numbers with the space does work for the output you want.

```
 grep -oP '[0-9]+.[0-9]+ '
```

If you don't have a space between the decimal point and the `%`, this would work as well,

```
grep -oP '[0-9]+.[0-9]+.*?(?=%)'
```

Answer (score 0):

extend it with:

`... | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"`

if you just looking for "Number Dot Number" or with:

`... | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+"`

for all numbers with probably an dot between.

Answer (score 0):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
s='pie(x=x,labels=c("5.3 %","2.8 %","1.5 %","5.2 %","2.9 %","2.3 %","7.9 %","16.9 %","19.5 %","27.5 %","8.3 %"),main="ChIP",col=c("#445FA2","#EB9D86","#799F7A","#6C527F","#5FA1C1","#E8BB77","#A8C5EF","#FDCDB9","#C6E6B5","#F1D5EE","#B4E1F6"),clockwise=TRUE,border=FALSE,radius=0.9,cex=0.8,init.angle=90,density=100)'

awk -v FPAT='"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ %"' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/[^.0-9]+/,"",$i); print $i } }' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
5.3
2.8
1.5
5.2
2.9
2.3
7.9
16.9
19.5
27.5
8.3
```